# how can i get the interface implementation of a generic interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class with the following class/interface structures:

```
public class Foo : IBar<FooBar>, INonGenericBar
{
    // class implementation
     public override IsGeneric => return true;
     public override IsNonGeneric => return true;
}

public IBar<T>
{
    bool isGeneric {get;}
}

public INonGenericBar
{
    bool IsNonGeneric {get;}
}
```

I know can get the implementation of INonGenericBar with the `is` and `as` keywords;

```
var myFoo = new Foo();
var barIsNonGeneric = myFoo is INonGenericBar;
Assert.IsTrue(barIsNonGeneric);
var nonGenericBar = myFoo as INonGeneric;
Assert.IsTrue(nonGenericBar.IsNonGeneric);
```

but since IBar is a generic interface, it seems I need to know the exact generic implemenatation

```
var myFoo = new Foo();
var isGenericBar = myFoo is IBar<FooBar>
var isParentGenericBar = myFoo is IBar<object>

Assert.IsTrue(isGenericBar);
Assert.IsFalse(isParentGenericBar);

var GenericBar = myFoo as IBar<FooBar>;
var GenericParentBar = myFoo as IBar<object>;

Assert.IsNotNull(GenericBar);
Assert.IsNotNull(GenericParentBar); // fails
```

I am however only intrested in the IBar<> interface itself, not the generic type it uses. Is there a way for me I can cast it to IBar<>?

Comment: You can't cast to `IBar<>` because generic interfaces get substituted into at runtime - the CLR creates a specialised type to represent each possible combination of parameters supplied to a generic type. Technically `IBar<>` as a class/object can't exist (you can't instantiate it, therefore you can't cast to it), but it does exist as type metadata. You can use reflection to inspect instance metadata which will give you enough to achieve what you want (as per the comment above).

Comment: There is no such type in c# as `IBar<>` without the generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to make `IBar<T>` covariant. After that, you can do this without getting a null:

```
var GenericParentBar = myFoo as IBar<object>;
```

To make `IBar<T>` covariant, simply add the `out` modifier in the generic parameter;

```
public IBar<out T>
{
    bool isGeneric {get;}
}
```

Note that after this change, you can't add any methods to `IBar` that takes a `T` as a parameter. You can only add methods that return `T`.

To learn more about variance, go to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: The OP is not asking about generic type parameter covariance, they are only asking about the ability to use members of generic types that do not depend on generic type parameters.

Comment: @Dai I came to the conclusion that what the OP needs is variance, because casting to `IBar<object>` what they seem to be trying to do in the posted code. I believe this is an equally valid interpretation of the question as well.

Comment: even if I add the <code>out</code> modifier, I still get a null when I cast to <code>IBar<object></code>. I only added the <code>out</code> modifier to the interface, nothing else.

Comment: @martijn [cannot reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BEtH61). Did you do `myFoo is IBar<object>`? That won't work.

Comment: i used `var covariantBar = myFoo as IBar<object>`

Comment: @martijn As you can see from the link I gave, I cannot reproduce this behaviour. The last line of the output is `Foo`, which means that it's not `null`. Note that the code in your question actually contains multiple errors, including but not limited to, misspelling of `IsGeneric` in interface declaration, extraneous `override` modifier, missing property type, extraneous `return` token... So you can't just add the `out` modifier, you'd have to fix all these typos, which are unrelated to this question, as well. I have fixed them for you in the link I gave.

Answer (score 4):

C# does not support the concept of "generic types, but I don't care about the type parameters" - this is why many libraries with generic classes put all of their non-generic members in a non-generic superclass (or generic interfaces putting their non-generic members in a non-generic parent interface).[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)

(Oddly enough, [Java **does** support this scenario](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html), but (ironically) this is only because Java's generics are implemented using type-erasure instead of .NET's  reified-generics[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html))

That said, C# *does* let you get the "open type" of a generic type with `typeof` operator - but only in the context of runtime reflection - so you cannot use it in normal program code.

So this is okay:

```
Type openType = typeof(IBar<>);
```

But this is not:

```
IBar<> anyIBar = ...
```

**The only solution in C#** is to refactor-move all of the members of `IBar` that don't depend on `T` to `INonGenericBar`.

As per my understanding of the .NET CLR: if any other CLR language wants to support this feature they would have to also implement this via some kind of reflection hack because the CLR itself does not support runtime references to generic objects without type parameters (I might be wrong!)

#### UPDATE!

Apparently Microsoft is aware of requests for support for "wildcard generics" and this GitHub issue is tracking the task - but don't expect this to be implemented for *years* - considering it took **54 years** ([from Tony Hoare's 1965 invention of the null reference](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare/) to C# 8.0's implementation of non-null reference types) so don't hold your breath.

---

[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) This is definitely a design mistake of the C# language and/or the .NET CLR because it effectively breaks generic inheritance (i.e. each generic type `Dog<T>` *may* need a non-generic parent `Dog`, but if you have a generic child `SamoyedDog<T>`, then that too may need a non-generic parent `SamoyedDog`, but C# and the .NET CLR will not allow `SamoyedDog<T>` to derive from both `SamoyedDog` and `Dog<T>`.

[2](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare/) I consider this ironic[3] because the whole point of reified generics is to have "first-class" generics instead of Java's *second-class* generics that only matter at compile-time - it's ironic that the end-result of Java's implementation enables (in this case at least) greater flexibility which is the intended result of first-class reified generics. I note (provided this is a CLR limitation) that the .NET CLR and C# *could* support parameter-less generics in a straightforward manner, but the demand just isn't there because the alternative (i.e. refactoring) is much simpler and the C#/.NET CLR team decided to spend their efforts on other new features.

[3] As someone who is British and *not* American, I take pride in using irony correctly!

Comment: @Liam That answer is using parameter-less generic types in a reflection context, not a normal program context (i.e. using `typeof`) which my answer addresses. You cannot use `IList<>` as a type identifier outside of `typeof`, for example

Comment: i wanted to cast it to IBar<>

Comment: @martijn You can't. And you have my sympathy. All we can do is complain to Microsoft and threaten to learn Haskell instead.